# Magento 1.9 Event Calendar

Tags: magento-1.9, database

I am looking for a free event manager extension that can list events in a list instead of a full calendar. and also that event information sent to all the customer, so please recommend the suitable extensions

Comment: "Shopping list" questions are not a good fit for StackExchange Q&A
(see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/158809/why-are-shopping-list-questions-bad) -
you'll get better results at the Magento forums (https://community.magento.com/t5/Find-an-Extension-that/bd-p/find-extension)
or Reddit (http://www.reddit.com/r/Magento)